# How to solve a algebraic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

My maths teacher gave me this equation and I really don't know how to solve this:
$$\overline{abc}+\overline{ab}+\overline{bc}+\overline{ac}+a+b+c=29,$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$  are digits.

I need to find how many three digit numbers are there which satisfy this.

Comment: Does $A = a$, $B = b$, etc.?

Comment: Yes. I am on phone. Autocorrect did that

Answer (score 1):

You have three equations in three unknowns. From the least significant digit (take the rightmost digit of each term) you have

$$c + b + c + a + b + c = 9$$

From the next digit you have $$b + a + b + a = 2$$

From the most significant digit you have $$a = 0$$ noting that $29 = 029$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: If a is zero, abc is not a three digit number

Comment: You're overlooking the possibility of a carry.

Comment: This would be $c+b+c+a+b+c \equiv 9 \mod 10$. Watch out for carries. If $c+b+c+a+b+c > 9$, then you need to add a number (carry a 1,2,3,4 or 5) to the next digit.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that.question edited

Comment: @Ryder: True. But if $a\ne 0$, the left-hand side must be larger than $29$. However, if $a=0$, the left-hand side is even, so there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well write it as $100a+10b+c+10a+b+10b+c+10a+c+a+b+c=29=121a+22b+4c$ , so you get $a=0$ but also no integers for $b$ and $c$ satisfy it. so no solution.